# Having problems with Fancybox (P

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to add Fancybox to my ASP.NET MVC application but I'm having some troubles.

As you can see, I added references to jQuery and Fancybox. The css is incapsulated inside of my style.css. And all the pictures are in the right place.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
```

Well, I added this lines to fire up the Fancybox plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.zoom").fancybox(); // The a with zoom class
    });

</script>
```

Then I have the link:

```
<a class="zoom" href="http://www.nytimes.com">This goes to iframe</a>
```

But when I click on the link I get a: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Permission denied 
[alt text http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/7738/screenshot20091123at352.png](http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/7738/screenshot20091123at352.png)

And this is my screen after that:
[alt text http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/7738/screenshot20091123at352.png](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/7738/screenshot20091123at352.png)

I don't know what to do. I'm desperate because I've spent all my day trying to figuring out what's happening. Please, help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the class 'iframe' to the link to tell fancybox to use an iframe to load the content to avoid a conflict with the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).   The same origin policy prevents the browser from downloading external content via AJAX. Alternatively it appears you can add a `?iframe` parameter to the URL and achieve the same effect.

Comment: Yeah, I did that and worked fine. Thanks. Now, how can I force to make an Ajax request instead of a HTTP request?

Comment: Again, you are right guys! If I add the iframe class the Fancybox doesn't make the request via Ajax. Removing the class from the link, it started automatically to make the ajax request. Thank you guys!! you saved my life. :)