# Fancybox Microsoft JScript runtime error: Permission denied

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, fancybox

I'm having this error Microsoft JScript runtime error: Permission denied, but still the function is working. There is just this annoying exclamation point on the status bar of IE. I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783649/having-problems-with-fancybox-p?answertab=oldest#tab-top) and looks like it's the solution. But can't get into it.

Anyway here are the screenshots:

[image: Using fancybox]
1.Using fancybox, I have this selection page to be shown, then press save...

[image: Result]

2. The page returned perfect result, but with the exclamation point in the browser status bar. When in VS2010 debug mode, the dialogbox Microsoft JScript runtime error: Permission denied is shown

Comment: What don't you understand?  What specifically is your question?

Comment: The answer posted was adding class 'iframe' on the link. I already declared iframe on the class, look at the sample code: `$(".statusPopLink").fancybox({
                'width': '25%',
                'height': '100%',
                'autoScale': false,
                'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
                'transitionIn': 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none',
                'type': 'iframe'
            }); `

Comment: I don't know how anyone can help you if you can't clarify.  Try again.. edit your original question, and make it a complete question on its own, and be specific about the problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. already edited with screenshots. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you crossing domains or internet zones with this iframe? Load up the tool fiddler and see where all the requests are going to . Its generally the solution to this issue when you request a local drive resource or certain cross domain scripts/requests with iframes. For instance if the parent tries to control an iframe in a different domain you will get this error.

Comment: There is no crossing of domains I think, for I am calling same controller functions. I am still struggling to get this thing done :(

Comment: did you run fiddler to ensure?